# jQuery UI is not working inside ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, sharepoint

I am trying to user `jQuery UI` to display dynamic data returned from ajax call

but I found that `jQuery-ui` stop working after my ajax call.

I checked console and it says:

> Uncaught Type Error: undefined is not a function

and here is a part of my code:

```
        function initialization(){

        $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
        var userid= _spPageContextInfo.userId;
        var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";
        var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };
        $.ajax({
            url : requestUri,
            contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers : requestHeaders,
            success : function(data){

                $("#accordion").append("<h3>Forth</h3><div>aaa</div>");
                $( "#accordion" ).accordion("refresh");

                var userEmail = data.d.Email;
                $("#userEmail").html(userEmail);
                retrieveListItem(userEmail);
            },
            error : displayError
        });

    }
```

`$( "#accordion" ).accordion();`  works but 
`$( "#accordion" ).accordion("refresh");`  returns error

Please help..

Comment: fron the console, Uncaught Type Error: undefined is not a function

Comment: like, for my code, jquery-ui only works at the beginning

Comment: do you have multiple versions of jQuery included in you page... try `jQuery( "#accordion" ).accordion("refresh");`

Comment: No i dont have multiple versions of jQuery. And I have used  `jQuery( "#accordion" ).accordion("refresh"); ` it only works if it is not inside the ajax call, returns error otherwise

Comment: as a debugging step try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0959sg4k/1/

Comment: what u meant for `jQuery( "#accordion" ).accordion("refresh");` ??

Comment: I want to add accordion options after ajax returns data

Comment: All I want is just use `.accordion()` call inside ajax success callback. but for some reasons it doesn't work